# How to convert a string list to integer in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following list of values:

```
DATA =  [['5', '1'], ['5', '5'], ['3', '1'], ['6', '1'], ['4', '3']]
```

How can I convert it to :

```
DATA = [[5, 1], [5, 5], [3, 1], [6, 1], [4, 3]]
```

Note : I have already tried the following but all are not working in **Python 3** :

```
   1. DATA = [int(i) for i in DATA] 
   2. DATA = list(list(int(a) for a in b) for b in DA if a.isdigit())
   3. DATA = [map(int,x) for x in DATA]
```

Please help me with this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your third one is actually correct. In Python 3 [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns a map object, so you just have to call `list` on it to get a *list*.

```
DATA =  [['5', '1'], ['5', '5'], ['3', '1'], ['6', '1'], ['4', '3']]

d = [list(map(int, x)) for x in DATA]

# Output:
# [[5, 1], [5, 5], [3, 1], [6, 1], [4, 3]]

# type of one of the items in the sublist
# print(type(d[0][0])
# <class 'int'>
```